# WSO2 Authentication error while reading swagger file from private git repository

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Recently we changed all our git repositories from public to private and tried uploading/publishing swagger files in WSO2,looks like WSO2 doesn’t like repository to be private. Is there a way to pass credentials to access private git repo

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to download and upload a file.

Comment: Is there any limitations for WSO2 to get swagger file only from public repo?.

Comment: there is no way to pass credentials.